# want to convert "00:10:00" to a single integer in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, procedure

There are many documents in the collection which contains this field `timeTaken: "00:10:00"`,

I want to sum up from all the documents and have to give a single integer in mongodb robo3T.

That is for the following documents:

```
[
  { timeTaken: "00:10:00" },
  { timeTaken: "01:10:00" },
  { timeTaken: "02:20:50" }
]
```

I want the result to be:

```
{ timeTaken: "03:40:50" }
```

Comment: You want to change it into `10`? what would `00:00:12` be changed into? what would `12:11:10`?

Comment: hello i want to add two fields of the same format 00:10:00, 00:00:12..How to add two fields into the same format

Comment: You'll have to edit in sample input and expected output. i'm not sure exactly what you want currently

Comment: Hello there is a field in every document of the collection ..00:10:00 like this which is time taken for a task ..so i want to add all these fields of this format from that collection

Comment: So i'm guessing it's HH:MM:SS format?

Comment: yes and how to add them ..

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Hello can you suggest anything ..i need it

Answer (score 1):

Our strategy will be to split the string into `minutes`, `seconds` and `hours`, convert them to numbers, sum them up and then reconstruct the structure.

For this you will need access to operators like [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) and [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) which means you can only do this for version 4.0+, for older Mongo versions you will have to read the documents and do this in code.

I've split the following query into multiple stages so it's clearer what I'm doing but this could be re-written into just 2 stages, the `$group` stage and a final `$project` stage to restructure the data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      dataParts: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$data",
              ":"
            ]
          },
          as: "num",
          in: {
            "$toInt": "$$num"
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      seconds: {
        $sum: {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$dataParts",
            2
          ]
        }
      },
      minutes: {
        $sum: {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$dataParts",
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      hours: {
        $sum: {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$dataParts",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      finalSeconds: {
        $mod: [
          "$seconds",
          60
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      minutes: {
        $sum: [
          "$minutes",
          {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  "$seconds",
                  "$finalSeconds"
                ]
              },
              60
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      finalMinutes: {
        $mod: [
          "$minutes",
          60
        ]
      },
      finalHours: {
        $sum: [
          "$hours",
          {
            $mod: [
              {
                $max: [
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      "$minutes",
                      60
                    ]
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              60
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      final: {
        $concat: [
          {
            "$toString": "$finalHours"
          },
          ":",
          {
            "$toString": "$finalMinutes"
          },
          ":",
          {
            "$toString": "$finalSeconds"
          },
          
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5W5vBwIDycM)